# Change of basis problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let 
$$v = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
7\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$w = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
-1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Let $B = (v,w)$ and $$A = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1&2\\
-1&0\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Find $[A]_B$

My thinking:

Let C be a change of basis matrix from basis $B$ to the standard basis $S$ whose column vectors are the the vectors $v,w$ then the first column of $[A]_B$ is

$C^-1*v$

and the second is

$C^-1*w$

Comment: what does $[A]_B$ mean ?

Comment: The matrix $A$ with respect to the basis $B$ I think. The problem does not explain further.

Comment: Sorry mistake! I will fix it! Its $w=<2,-1>$

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is this, we have a basechange matrix $P$ from the standard basis $E=(e_{1}, e_{2})$ to the basis $B=(v,w)$. The matrix $P$ is essentially 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &2 \\ 
7 &-1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$

This matrix has a nonzero determinant so it is invertible, making it a justifiable base-change matrix.

New matrix $A'$ with respect to this basis will be $P^{-1}AP$

**A great reference for this material is chapter 4 of Artin's Algebra.**

Question:
 You originally had a linear map $T: (\mathbb{R}^{2}, {E}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}, {E})$. I used the notation $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, E)$ to signify the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with basis $E$. (The linear transformation given by $A$ with respect to this basis is the linear map which maps $(1,0) \mapsto (1,7)$ and $(0,1) \mapsto (2,-1)$)

When you write the columns of $A$ in terms of the new basis what you have essentially have done is change the basis in the target vector vector space. That is,you now have a map $T:(\mathbb{R}^{2}, E) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{2}, B)$. In more detail we have that the basechange matrix $PE=B$ which implies that $E=P^{-1}B$, so writing the columns of $A$ which were orginally in terms of $E$ in terms of $B$ is the same as multiplying by $P^{-1}$, you can even solve the systems of equations to verify.

What you want is a map $T: (\mathbb{R}^{2}, B) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{2},B)$. For that you need to $P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: Since the matrix $A$ changes the coordinates of vectors in the standard basis can't I say that if I change the column vectors of $A$ to vectors with respect to basis $B$ then that will also work too?

Comment: Is this what you are asking: if we write the columns of $A$ in terms of the basis $B$, will that also work?

Comment: That is exactly it

Comment: Okay well, when you do that you actually get $P^{-1}A$. Which is not quite right

Comment: I can write up an detailed explanation tonight, by editing my answer if you are still unsure, just tell me if you are still unsure and I will write more when I have time.

Comment: Yes please do that!

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to understand it and I have been trying all day

Comment: I added some details, if you still don't understand please see if you can get a hold of Artin's Algebra and take a good look at chapter 4. I hope I was able to help somewhat.